# jQuery Ajax -get JSON data 1 Million rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, database

I want to fetch  **1 Million** rows using jQuery AJAX or data come from server successfully .
but gave me error on client side.

Note:
**600000** rows successfully  display when the limit  increase it give me error.
this is my code

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/Api/Reports/SaleSummaryFlexmonster",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify(args),
    success: function (result) {
        if (result.SuccessFlag) {
            $("#FlexmonsterLoader").hide();
            Flex((result.Data));
        }
        else
            return ShowMessage('No data Found', 'error', 'error');

        // return deferred.promise();
    },
    error: function () {
        console.log("Data Loading Error");
    }
});
```

if recode more then 60,000 then this console show and i update question
with screenshot. check this Attachment  https://prnt.sc/uyd933

Maybe browser not support greater than 600000 rows.
but not exactly confirm.

If not show then gave me this on console
[image: if not show then gave me this on console]

My question is when limit increase from 600000 then why not show ?
is there any Ajax limit?

Comment: Are you sure that's the correct error?  And you *only* get that console info if >60,000 rows?  It's a chrome-standard error message about cookies.

Comment: Not Sure. thats why i said may be this error,

Comment: But my question is when limit increase from 600000 then why not show ?
is there any Ajax limtt?

Comment: Yes 60,000 Ok. after that there is no gave me response. i update my question.

Comment: Ok, maybe someone else can help you as the cookie response is still bogging down the question.  There's no "ajax limit".  But there might be a limit on your server.  Check the browser network tab to see exactly what's being returned.

Comment: if recode more then 60,000 then this console show and i update question
with screenshot. check this Attachment  https://prnt.sc/uyd933

Comment: {"readyState":4,"responseText":"","status":200,"statusText":"OK"} in console gave me this

Comment: https://prnt.sc/uye484 at Browser network tab

Comment: Instead of working on how to successfully get one million rows at once, I'm going to ask _why_ you think you need one million rows at once

Comment: i need this data and show in  Pivot . am using "Flexmonster pivot Grid". so one moth data is 120,0000 rows .thats it.

Comment: Please any body help me.